# How to Create Database for Storage Room

Tags: database, oracle

i wanted to create via Excel or Oracle a database for a Storage room that is filled with all kinds of Computer parts and stuff.

I never created something like that, so i wanted to know if you could help me out giving me an advice how to create a database for a beginner

It should be possible to  insert and remove parts or even update them

Hope my question is readable and understandable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple option to do that - not only the table so that you could write your own DML statements (to insert, update or delete rows) - but to create a nice application - is to use Oracle Application Express (Apex).

Depending on database version you use, it might already be installed by default. If not, ask your DBA to install it.

Alternatively, create a free account on [apex.oracle.com](https://apex.oracle.com/en/); you'll get limited space (more than enough to do what you want to do).

In Application Builder, use the Excel file you have as a "source" which will then be used by Apex's wizard to create a table in the database, as well as application, true GUI which works and looks just fine.

---

If you don't have *anything* at all, not even an Excel file, well ... that's another problem and requires some more work to be done.

- you have to know what you want (OK, a *storage room*)
- is a single table enough to contain all information you'd want to collect?

  - if so, which columns (attributes) do you want to collect?
  - if not (for example, you'd want to "group" items), you'd need at least two tables which will be related to each other by the means of master-detail relationship, which also means that you'll have to create a foreign key constraint
- which datatypes are appropriate for certain attributes? You wouldn't store item names into `number` datatype, right? Nor should you put dates (when item entered the storage room) as a string in `varchar2` column, but into a `date` datatype column
- etc.

Basically, YMMV.

Comment: Ok great thanks for this fast answer, i already have a excel file with all the data of the storage room. but its a simple excel file just wrote the items and all

but the idea was to create a database where i can  insert, delete, update the items.

Thanks for that mate :)